# Use Sprockets Directive Inside Rails 3.2 CoffeeScript View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sprockets

I'm using a file at `app/views/api/index.js.coffee` to `respond_to` a the js format of a request to `/api/:api_key`. I can see that the CoffeeScript compiles correctly to JS and can use ERB inside the CoffeeScript file as well.

However, now I'm trying to require an external file into this CoffeeScript file via a Sprockets directive and it doesn't appear to work.

I'm basically adding

```
#= require jquery
```

to the first line of the CoffeeScript file. I'd expect the jQuery library to be imported and added to my resulting JavaScript file, but it does not show up. It's as if the directive is being ignored.

Is it possible to use Sprockets directives inside a CoffeeScript view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple competing issues here:

1. Because of how the asset pipeline works, if you let your coffeescript be an asset (for example, in public/assets/javascript), your ERb will be evaluated at asset compile time, not when the javascript is rendered by your controller. This means it's fine to use directives like `image_path`, but you can't use things like `current_user` inside erb.
2. Sprockets directives are only for files that are compiled as part of the asset pipeline. In a view, you can use `javascript_tag` to reference a javascript assembly, but it doesn't make sense to require something here, since it's not being compiled. This can actually lead to better design, where you put library code into public/assets (or lib/assets), and then custom code into the view.

Also, I should note that if you're going to use the `require` sprockets directives, don't forget to `require self` somewhere in there to load the contents of that file as well.

Comment: Pretty much what I'm trying to do isn't possible. :) And it makes sense why. It'd be pretty slow to pass all the views through ERB and Sprockets as well. Thanks for your help.